# Add route in Blazor server side app for .json or .js file to be handled by controller

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

This seems like it should be simple but cannot quite work out how.

I want to be able to make a file in the root of the application to by dynamically served.

i.e.

https://localhost:5000/test.json

to be handled by a controller. Its easy if you just have a path without a . but if its a json or js file it seems to get handled differently by the server.

Comment: I have seen plenty of posts with how to do this with older versions of mvc but not the latest.

Comment: if anyone asks why its because I am writing a multi tenanted pwa app. so I want to be able to dynamically change the "manifest.json" so the application name when installing to desktop is different depending on the tenant.

Answer (score 1):

ok really simple - just needed to do this in startup.cs

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGet("/test.js", context => context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world"));
    });
```